# NaNs arise unexpectedly in C code mixed with assembly that uses x87 floating point

Tags: c, function, x86, sse, clock

My C code is the following. It calls an assembly function.

```
clock_t t = clock();
asmfunction(input);
t = clock() - t;
printf("%.5f\n", ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

I use assembly x86-32+SSE for `asmfunction`.

I can’t understand why the second `clock()` invocation returns nan.

My assembly code is a cycle which makes procedures call. I noticed that if it iterates more than six time, the second call of clock function returns NaN. Otherwise it works normally.

This is the core of my assembly code:

```
do_while:
    push dword [eax+n]
    push eax
    push ecx
    push dword [eax+p]
    call function1
    add esp,16

    push dword [eax+n]
    push eax
    push ecx
    call function2
    add esp,12      

    fst qword[res]

    push dword [eax+n]
    push eax
    push ecx
    call function3  ;function3 returns a double precision floating 
                    ;point value
    add esp,12 
    movsd xmm1,[res] ;xmm1=res

    comisd xmm1,[eax+ex] ; eax+ex is a quadword
    ja do_while
```

Why is the result of the `clock` call a NaN?

Comment: You haven't given enough information. `clock_t` can be an integer or floating point type. If the former, then it's perfectly reasonable for the integer value to correspond to `nan` in floating point. If you are saying that the `printf` prints `nan` then you can't conclude the problem is the second call to `time()`. The assembly could be munging `t` on the stack. You must find the point where what _you think the code is doing_ diverges from what _it's actually doing_. Standard debugging techniques: debugger; printing values, binary search cutting out sections of code.

Comment: Another alternative is to extract an MCVE, as per site guidelines.

Comment: Why do,you use `fst` rather than `fstp`? Is `asm_function` or the functions it calls overflowing the eight-entry floating-point stack in the processor? Are they leaving elements on the stack after `asm_function` returns? If you bollyx the floating-point stack, that could explain NaNs.

Comment: `printf("%lld %e\n", (long long)t, (double) t);` please report this output when placed just before `printf("%.5f\n"...`

Comment: No, @Gene, the standard specifies that `clock_t` is a *real* type, not an integer type ([C2011 7.27.1/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p3)).  Moreover, it is *not* reasonable for a valid integer value to correspond to FP NaN, except in the sense of having the same bit pattern.  Even if such a bit pattern match occurred, however, it would be irrelevant to the OP's code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True for C11, but not true for all prior versions. The OP never gave an API. And an integer type having the same bit pattern as NaN in a floating point rep is exactly the point.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. @EricPostpischil proposal solved my problem. The problem was to use fstp rather than fst.

Comment: @Gene, I acknowledge that C99 requires only that `clock_t` be an arithmetic type, though it is unclear how relevant that is in 2018.  But an integer having the same bit pattern as NaN is no point at all, as there is nothing in the OP's code that would cause an integer bit pattern to be reinterpreted as a floating-point bit pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x87 FPU (Floating Point Unit) stack has only eight elements. If a routine does not pop all elements it pushes, the stack will quickly overflow with repeated uses of the routine. Once the stack overflows, floating point operations will produce NaNs (“floating point indefinite value” in Intel’s documentation).

The `fst` instruction in the assembly code in the question stores a value without popping the stack. Assuming one of the prior functions (`function1` or `function2`) pushed a floating point value onto the stack to return it to its caller, the caller should pop it from the stack, which can be done while storing it by using the `fstp` instruction instead of `fst`.

Comment: More specifically, the i386 System V calling convention requires that the x87 stack is empty on function call / return, or if the return type is FP, then return with the x87 stack empty except for the return value in `st(0)`.  So yes, the C compiler is expecting `asmfunction` to leave the x87 stack empty, but it almost certainly isn't (but we can't see the code for `function3`, so maybe it includes an `finit` or something, and the `double` it talks about returning is in `xmm0`?  Very much lacking a [mcve], but this answer is definitely the most likely.